# weird AJAX error

Tags: javascript, ajax

why won't this work?

```
function login(){

if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();
}else if(window.ActiveXObject){
ajax=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

ajax.onreadystatechange=validatelogin;

params='name='+escape(document.getElementById('name').value)+'&pass='+escape(document.getElementById('pass').value);

/*IT FAILS HERE*/
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 

ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-length",params.length);
ajax.setRequestHeader("Connection","close");

ajax.open('POST','login.php?login=true',true);
ajax.send(params);

}

function validatelogin(){
if(ajax.readyState===4){
if(ajax.status===200){
alert(ajax.responseText);
exit(0);
}else{
alert("FAIL!!!!!");
}
}
}
```

Firefox error consol complains about

> Error: Component returned failure
>   code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)
>   [nsIXMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader]

Comment: w35l3y is right. Apart from that, you shouldn't be using escape(), which is a special JavaScript-specific encoding scheme that is similar to, but incompatible with, URL-encoding. The function you should be using is encodeURIComponent(). And don't try to set the Content-Length and Connection headers, that's not part of your job as an XMLHttpRequest user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happened to me once.

You must call the "open" method before you call "setRequestHeader"

Answer (score 2):

In case it's useful, all of that code you have written could be replaced by this tiny bit of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.post('login.php?login=true', {name: $('#name'), pass: $('#pass')}, 
            function(response) {
                alert(response);
            }
    );
});
```

See [`jQuery.post`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post)

Comment: Less opportunity maybe, but there's still a missing-close-quote error!

Comment: @bobince - You could have fixed that you know. Thanks for the snarky comment.

Comment: @Hippo - The beginning of my answer says 'In case it's useful', and not 'this is your solution'. Thanks for down-voting.